# Why Laravel 7 Generates Views in /storage/framework/views/, and how to stop creating them?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, view, laravel-blade

Laravel keeps generating views simultaneously with the views I am editing.

```
-storage
   -framework
       -views
           -0e4e52af70801a529019b11f786c45e07ca41a01.php
           -2c29d7cd1ffcb89dff8d91bbd62bedc5176cb6fc.php
```

Comment: Those are the compiled versions of the Blade files you've created, i.e. the code Laravel actually runs to render the page. You shouldn't ever need to do anything with that directory, you can just ignore it. What problem are they causing?

Comment: @iainn they do not interfere in my code just, in the future might they cause a storage problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that but for that you have to edit Laravel's core files, it is not advisable.

You can delete the views generated in storage folder by using following artisan command.

```
php artisan view:clear
```